# Unity convert normal instantiated object to a photon pun instantiated object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon-pun

I want that my game works in single player and in multi-player. In single player mode, the player should no be connected to the internet so `PhotonNetwork.Instantiate` does not work. But when the player is connected to the internet and connects to Photon and creates a Room from in the Scene he is in the already instantiated object should be converted to like photon instaciated objects is it possible without destroying the original object?

I have tried looking up a solution or an question like mine but I have not found one.

Comment: Could probably go through [Manual Instantiation](https://doc.photonengine.com/pun/current/gameplay/instantiation#manual_instantiation) via RaiseEvent passing on according required information (what object to spawn + new ViewID)